# Getting email addresses via while loop and sending php email

Tags: php, html, email, loops, while-loop

I am attempting to send a message to all users on my site with the group of 5. However, the way I have this email form structured, I am getting my if statement response come back saying the email address was not filled in.

I'm trying to add the email address through a while loop like this..

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $to = $user_email;
}
```

I am sending the subject and message through my form via AJAX. I am not getting any errors from that. This is the part I get sent back to me onto my page..

```
 else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}
```

What am I doing wrong for this to say an email address was not filled in? Also if I have more than one user's email address, would the way I have it work or would I need to structure the `$to` differently?

Here is the full code:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


try {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", ""); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error()); 
        exit(); 
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, email, username FROM users WHERE `group` IN (5)");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
         // Check Errors for prepare
            die('User/Player SELECT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
            die('User/Player SELECT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
     $stmt->store_result();
} catch (Exception $e ) {
    die("User/Player SELECT execute() failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
    $stmt->bind_result($userid, $user_email, $username);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $to = $user_email;
}           
            $subject = 'Updated Status';
            $message = '';

            $from = "surveys@example.com";
            $Bcc = "surveys_check@example.com";

            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            // Additional headers
            //$headers .= 'To: ' .$to;//. "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$Bcc. "\r\n"; 

            // Send the email
            //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            //if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
              //   echo "Success";
            //} else { 
              //   print_r(error_get_last());
               //  echo "Fail";
            //}


            if (!empty($email)) { 
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

        //Should also do a check on the mail function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
        }

    } else { 
        //Invalid email
        echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
    }

} else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `$user_email` value from ?

Comment: From my bind_result `$stmt->bind_result($userid, $user_email, $username);`

Comment: Yes you are correct. My bad. `while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $to = $user_email;
} ` I think this will just override the `$to` value. Maybe you need to wrap the whole mail sending logic in that while loop.

Comment: It doesn't appear that `$email` is being defined.

Comment: Additionally, you can iterate through the query result using while and build an array of email addresses. Then you can iterate through that array to send email to EACH address in that array.

Comment: @mattslone that worked!! Thanks.

Comment: However, when I have more than one email this code dies. Can I simply do `$to = $user_email . ',' .;` ?

Comment: You should be able to just add the comma, `$to .= $user_email . ','`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like $email is not being defined. You could check for `$to` instead of `$email` in :

```
if (!empty($email)) { 
    ...
}
```

so:

```
if (!empty($to)) { 
    ...
}
```

For multiple recipients, use this:

```
$to .= $user_email . ',';
```

after defining `$to = '';` before your while loop

Comment: Perfect! I did this though `if (!empty($user_email)) {` Should I do `$to` instead? Does it make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't, you should be fine :)

please accept my answer if it helped thx